# Primefaces 5.0 tabs close listener not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

The TabCloseEvent is not getting fired if tabs generated from backing bean.
TabCloseEvent is working fine with normal xhtml tabs.

Here is my code

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
        <h:head>
            <title>Test Title</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h:form id="form">
                <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />

                <p:tabView id="tabview"
                           value="#{TestBean.tabList}"
                           var="tab"
                           widgetVar="tabviewV">

                    <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{TestBean.onTabCloseAction}"  update=":form:growl"/>
                    <p:tab id="tab"  title="#{tab}" closable="true" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{tab}"/>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:tabView>

            </h:form>

        </h:body>
    </html>
```

the managed bean

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "TestBean")
    @ViewScoped
    public class TestBean {

        private List<String> tabList = new ArrayList<String>();

        public TestBean() {
            tabList.add("Test Tab 1");
            tabList.add("Test Tab 2");
            tabList.add("Test Tab 3");
            tabList.add("Test Tab 4");
        }

        public void onTabCloseAction(TabCloseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Tab Closed Event : " + event.getTab().getTitle());
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Tab Closed", "Closed tab: " + event.getTab().getTitle());
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }

        public List<String> getTabList() {
            return tabList;
        }

        public void setTabList(List<String> tabList) {
            this.tabList = tabList;
        }
    }
```

I'm using Primefaces 5.0. also I tried using process="@this" in side p:ajax but result is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the way it was mentioned in the showcase as well as in your code but does not work fully so i tried another approach lets have look

Facelets

```
  <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
<p:tabView id="tabView" binding="#{homeBean.tabView}" >

        <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{homeBean.onTabClose}" update=":form:growl"/>

    </p:tabView>
```

Managed Bean

```
    private TabView tabView = new TabView();

    Tab tab1 = new Tab();
    tab1.setClosable(true);
    tab1.setTitle("Business Partner");
    Tab tab2 = new Tab();
    tab2.setClosable(true);
    tab2.setTitle("Manage Favorites");
    tabView.getChildren().add(tab1);
    tabView.getChildren().add(tab2);
```

now it seems to be working.
Note : I used Primefaces 5.0

Comment: Thanks psi. It's working but event.getTab() is getting null. Any idea how to get object of closed tab.I tried event.getComponent() and event.getSource() both return TabView object.

Comment: Ya you can get object of closed tab by using event.getTab()
i am getting it by using the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6815&can=1&q=label%3DTargetVersion-5.0.2%20status%3AFixed&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Summary).

It has been [fixed in 5.0.2 version](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list?can=1&q=label%3DTargetVersion-5.0.2+status%3AFixed&sort=&groupby=&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Priority+TargetVersion+Reporter+Summary&nobtn=Update).

So you should just update your library to 5.0.2 or 5.0.3